# Setting permissions on list of values in bug process template

Tags: tfs

I created a new field in our bug template that has values like A,B,C,D. Now I’d like to set permissions for that specific field so that only one group of TFS users can update it while others see it as read=only. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by editing the Work Item Type definition and edit your field. Switch to the Rules tab and add a "ReadOnly" rule. For this rule, insert the allowed group in the Not textbox, so this rule will not be taken into consideration for them (example for Description field):

```
<FieldDefinition name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML">
 <READONLY not="[Project]\AllowedGroup" />
</FieldDefinition>
```